# Interfaces have same methods but are considered as different

Tags: go

Why two named interfaces with same methods are treated as different ones - and how can you avoid that?

So let's say we have a guy who likes to eat products (Eater). He doesn't care what products he eats, he only wants to be pointed out from where he can fetch new products. In other words he wants product service, but doesn't care what products product service will produce. In concrete implementation we will try to feed him with apples, so we will provide him with appleService.

Here is the result:

```
./main.go:9: cannot use appleService (type *service.AppleService) as type eater.ProductServiceI in function argument:
        *service.AppleService does not implement eater.ProductServiceI (wrong type for New method)
                have New() service.ProductI
                want New() eater.ProductI
```

Interfaces `service.AppleI` and `eater.AppleI` have same method `Eat()` and nothing else but golang considers them as different ones. Why and how to avoid that? According to duck typing this should work because what actually `ProductServiceI` requires is that provided struct has `Eat()` method - it shouldn't care about what name has interface (`service.ProductI` vs `eater.ProductI`).

Below is full code:

==> ./main.go <==

```
package main

import "./apple/service"
import "./eater"

func main() {
    appleService := &service.AppleService{}
    // func eater.New(productService ProductServiceI)
    appleEater := eater.New(appleService) 
    appleEater.EatUntilHappy()
}
```

==> ./eater/eater.go <==

```
package eater

type ProductServiceI interface {
    New() ProductI
}

type ProductI interface {
    Eat()
}

type Eater struct {
    productService ProductServiceI
}

func New(productService ProductServiceI) *Eater {
    return &Eater{
        productService: productService,
    }
}

func (a *Eater) EatUntilHappy() {
    for i:=0; i < 5; i++ {
        product := a.productService.New()
        product.Eat()
    }
}
```

==> ./apple/service/service.go <==

```
package service

import "./apple"

type ProductI interface {
    Eat()
}

type AppleService struct {
}

func (a *AppleService) New() ProductI {
    return &apple.Apple{}
}
```

==> ./apple/service/apple/apple.go <==

```
package apple

import "fmt"

type Apple struct {
}

func (a *Apple) Eat() {
    fmt.Println("mniam, mniam")
}
```

I thought it doesn't matter what name or what import path has interface as long as declaration is the same.

Comment: 1. Don't write Java in Go, this won't work. 2. service.AppleI and AppleI are completely different types, duck typing works on struct types as structs implement interface. 3. Why do both packages main and service provide their own (and different) AppleI? Just use one and it will work.

Comment: I think you just misunderstood something. One type that has the method Eat() will implement BOTH interfaces, but they are different as interfaces. Go is strict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer my own question

Firstly I just found out answer about why those interfaces are not considered similar in go in their official faq: http://golang.org/doc/faq#t_and_equal_interface

> Why doesn't type T satisfy the Equal interface?
>
> Consider this simple interface to represent an object that can compare
> itself with another value:
>
> type Equaler interface {
> Equal(Equaler) bool }
>
> and this type, T:
>
> type T int func (t T) Equal(u T) bool { return t == u } // does not
> satisfy Equaler
>
> Unlike the analogous situation in some polymorphic type systems, T
> does not implement Equaler. The argument type of T.Equal is T, not
> literally the required type Equaler.
>
> In Go, the type system does not promote the argument of Equal; that is
> the programmer's responsibility, as illustrated by the type T2, which
> does implement Equaler:
>
> type T2 int func (t T2) Equal(u Equaler) bool { return t == u.(T2) }
> // satisfies Equaler
>
> Even this isn't like other type systems, though, because in Go any
> type that satisfies Equaler could be passed as the argument to
> T2.Equal, and at run time we must check that the argument is of type
> T2. Some languages arrange to make that guarantee at compile time.
>
> A related example goes the other way:
>
> type Opener interface {    Open() Reader }
>
> func (t T3) Open() *os.File
>
> In Go, T3 does not satisfy Opener, although it might in another
> language.
>
> While it is true that Go's type system does less for the programmer in
> such cases, the lack of subtyping makes the rules about interface
> satisfaction very easy to state: are the function's names and
> signatures exactly those of the interface? Go's rule is also easy to
> implement efficiently. We feel these benefits offset the lack of
> automatic type promotion. Should Go one day adopt some form of
> polymorphic typing, we expect there would be a way to express the idea
> of these examples and also have them be statically checked.

Secondly in my case I can use anonymous interface `interface { Eat() }` instead of declaring `type ProductI interface { Eat() }`

But in case of examples from go faq **that is not possible**. Consider this:

```
type Equaler interface {
    Equal(Equaler) bool
}

type T int
func (t T) Equal(u Equaler) bool { return t == u.(T) }
```

If you would use the same trick here you will get

```
type T int
func (t T) Equal(u interface{ Equal(interface{ Equal(...) bool }) bool }) bool { return t == u.(T) }
```

In other words you end up with recursion - ups

Below is my updated code with this trick - it works - someone might find this trick useful.

==> ./eater/eater.go <==

```
package eater

type ProductServiceI interface {
    New() interface { Eat() }
}

type Eater struct {
    productService ProductServiceI
}

func New(productService ProductServiceI) *Eater {
    return &Eater{
        productService: productService,
    }
}

func (a *Eater) EatUntilHappy() {
    for i:=0; i < 5; i++ {
        product := a.productService.New()
        product.Eat()
    }
}
```

==> ./main.go <==

```
package main

import "./apple/service"
import "./eater"

func main() {
    appleService := &service.AppleService{}
    appleEater := eater.New(appleService)
    appleEater.EatUntilHappy()
}
```

==> ./apple/service/service.go <==

```
package service

import "./apple"

type AppleService struct {
}

func (a *AppleService) New() interface{ Eat() } {
    return &apple.Apple{}
}
```

==> ./apple/service/apple/apple.go <==

```
package apple

import "fmt"

type Apple struct {
}

func (a *Apple) Eat() {
    fmt.Println("mniam, mniam")
}
```

And the result :)

```
# go run main.go
mniam, mniam
mniam, mniam
mniam, mniam
mniam, mniam
mniam, mniam
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a couple of problems here.  For one, you have defined the `AppleI` interface twice, once in main and once in service.  Second, you seem to be trying to do Python or Java (I'm guessing) style packages. It's worth reading up on [packages](http://www.golang-book.com/11)

Here is a version of your code that compiles and runs.

==> kamil/main.go

```
package main

import (
    "kamil/service"
)

type Program struct {
    appleService service.AppleServiceI
}

func main() {
    program := &Program{
        appleService: &service.AppleService{},
    }

    apple := program.appleService.New()
    apple.Eat()
}
```

==> kamil/service/service.go

```
package service

import (
    "kamil/service/apple"
)

type AppleServiceI interface {
    New() AppleI
}

type AppleI interface {
    Eat()
}

type AppleService struct {
}

func (a *AppleService) New() AppleI {
    return &apple.Apple{}
}
```

==> kamil/service/apple/apple.go (unchanged)

```
package apple

import "fmt"

type Apple struct {
}

func (a *Apple) Eat() {
    fmt.Println("mniam, mniam")
}
```

That said, I don't think the approach you are taking is idiomatic GO and you will likely end up banging your head against it at some point :)

Comment: This doesn't actually answer my question - I've made one shortcut in my example code - and so you used it in the answer. I will fix up my example code soon, but the question remains. Why if I have two interfaces with same methods go doesn't treat them as same.

Comment: They aren't the same interface. They're declared in two different packages. GO doesn't examine the interface to determine that it's identical to some other interface. Think of them as kamil.AppleI and kamil.service.ApplI if that helps.

Comment: Yes, I know they are declared in different packages, but I thought that this shouldn't matter because in case of structs you implement interface if struct has needed methods. Why the same doesn't apply to interfaces? I've updated my question - sorry for changes:( But I think this example better shows the problem. And I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm afraid the *why* of it is something you'd have to ask on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts. An interface is still a type and as such if you define it in two places, you get two types. Those `New` methods don't return the same thing, therefore they can't satisfy the same interface.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completion: a very similar case (methods with same signature exists, but Go does not find them) can occur if you use private methods in an interface (lower case method name).

That way Go restricts its searches for the method to the package that defines the Interface and therefore does not find the method inside the package that implements the method.

Actually, as I cannot think of any sane reason to use private methods in a public interface: use the same visibility for the methods of an interface as for the interface itself.